# Unable to run pyspark 3.0.0 or pyspark 2.4.6 on MacOSx (with code that works on linux)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The python code I'm running:

```
# read input data -- search data for departure months (columns) across shopping days (rows)
df = pd.read_csv('test_arima_states_input.csv', header=0)

# format date columns
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
state_data = df[['State', 'date', 'Jul-20']]

spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(state_data)

results = spark_df.groupby('State').apply(run_arima_fcst)

results.show()
```

This error persistently comes up no matter what I try.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.showString.
: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class io.netty.buffer.UnsafeDirectLittleEndian cannot access 
its superclass io.netty.buffer.WrappedByteBuf
```

I've reinstalled python and pyspark numerous times and all of the pip packages. There aren't any additional JDK's on my machine other than the Java 8 version.

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace or error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the way to fix it, is to wipe your Mac clean and reinstall from scratch....bit excessive.